# Loss function and data format for training a ''categorical input' to 'categorical output' model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I am trying to train a model for autonomous driving that converts input from the front camera, to a bird's eye view image.

The input and output, both are segmentation masks with shape **(96, 144)** where each pixel has a range from  **0 to 12** (each number represents a different class).

Now my question is how should i preprocess my data and which loss function should i use for the model (I am trying to use a Fully convolutional Network).

I tried to convert input and outputs to shape ***(96, 144, 13)*** using keras' to_categorical utility so each channel has 0s and 1s of representing a specific mask of a category. I used `binary_crossentropy` ad `sigmoid` activation for last layer with this and the model seemed to learn and loss started reducing.

But i am still unsure if this is the correct way or if there are any better ways.

what should be the:

- input and ouptput data format
- activation of last layer
- loss function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, use categorical crossentropy with softmax activation at last layer. Use the same data format as specified in the question.